# Android get resource / Buffer reader problems

Tags: java, android, resources, inputstream, bufferedreader

**My code seems to run but it does not display the result any result on text view am guessing is because of the way I set my code. The code is below Somebody please help me. Thanks**

```
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.main3);

                Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but);

                input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextj);


                display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);


                button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        CCActivity3 fs = new CCActivity3();
                        fs.fileReader();

                    }// button
                });// button end
            }

            public void fileReader() {

                try {
                InputStream is=this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.file);

                BufferedReader bc = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

                    String cLine;
                    String inputText = "";

                    List<String> test2 = new ArrayList<String>();   

                    // read file line by line



                    while ((cLine = bc.readLine()) != null) {


                         inputText = inputText + cLine + "\n";

                    }



                    s = input.getText().toString();

                    test = CCActivity3.getPermutation(s);//Permutation method
                          test2.retainAll(test);//intersection
                    String fg = "";

                    for (String s2 : test2) {
                        fg += s2 + "\n";
                    }


                    display.setText(fg);




                     bc.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {// catch any errors if necessary

                    display.setText(e.getMessage());
                }




        }
```

If you check the resource line am very sure am not getting that right and also the formating of the code I believe they just scattered . Hint the file.txt on the res/raw path has more than 100,000 strings/words, could this be the cause.Thanks Again

Comment: You have stord inputstream lines in "inputText" and you have not used it after that i.e you are using "s" for getting string to display not "inputstream"

Comment: sorry i didn't put the declared variable for S. its actually an array list declared globally and the input does not relate to input text its from user input from the edit text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your code:

> ```
>             button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>                 public void onClick(View v) {
>                     CCActivity3 fs = new CCActivity3();
>                     fs.fileReader();
>
>                 }// button
>             });// button end
> ```

Is CCActivity3 derived from an Activity?
If so, then you shouldn't construct it this way.
You can't instantiate your own Activity class.  Only the Android framework can do that.
What seems to be happening here is that inside fileReader(), you are calling getResources() on an Activity whose Context has not yet been properly initialized by onCreate().

In any case, one thing you can do is call fileReader() method directly without instantiating CCActivity3, like so:

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            fileReader();
        }// button
    });// button end
```

Comment: OMG thank you so much,its working now. I just have one problem. Am reading more than 100,000 words from the file.txt. Is very slow that is crashes the app ,if it doesn't respond. Do you think I should write a code to compare it with letter instead of words, so it can be faster and productive. What do you think.

Comment: 100,000 words should not have that big a performance issue.  One thing I notice is that you are using String objects to concatenate two strings together.  Using String objects this way means the VM will create a String object instance for every word!  You might want to try to use a StringBuilder instead.  Make sure to instantiate only one StringBuilder object outside the loop.... Let us know if this improves your performance.  http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StringBuilder.html

Answer (score 0):

test = CCActivity3.getPermutation(s);//Permutation method 
test2.retainAll(test);//intersection

Above codes can get the right return?

Comment: hmmm i don't think so. But i got the correction from the above guy. Thanks for your effort.